# How to clear the configuration cache in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony2. I have a `config.yml` with users setting. In my development environment, if I change the list of users and refresh the browser, I see the change immediately. In production, I do not see the change, even though I have tried clearing the cache.  What do I need to do to see the configuration change in production?

Comment: How do you clear the cache? You run a command? If yes, which one and do you see an error when running it? Have you tried manually deleting the `cache` folder content?

Comment: have you tried to clear production cache, to be sure : `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

Comment: I am clearing with a "php console cache:clear --env=prod". No error messages. I went and cleared the cache manually, and, all seems to be working now. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to clear the production cache with this command :

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

It it doesn't work, clear the content of the cache folder.